# What is the difference between 10.1.8.09 and 10.1.8.9?

Tags: redirect, ip, protocols

Is there any difference between this two cause one of them is redirecting to other ip address

Comment: X-Ref: [Why does pinging 192.168.072 (only 2 dots) return a response from 192.168.0.58?](http://superuser.com/q/486788/63279)

Answer (score 2):

What program are you seeing this behavior with? [There has been a known issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation) where leading 0's were interpreted as octal.

Answer (score 1):

In your application '0' prefix may be treated as octal number as Darren already mentioned.
[this](https://superuser.com/questions/486788/why-does-pinging-192-168-072-only-2-dots-return-a-response-from-192-168-0-58) post would be intresting for you.